# Pig-latin translator parsing "qu" erratically

Tags: ruby

I'm working on the pig_latin_spec example from The Odin Project and having some difficulty handling special cases in which a word contains "qu" and those characters need to be treated as one phoneme. For example "quiet" => "ietquay" and "square" => "aresquay".

Here's the offending `if` statement:

```
if word.include? "qu"
    start_index = word.index("q")
    prefix = word[0..(start_index+1)] + "ay"
    pig_word = word[(start_index+2)..-1] + prefix
end
```

This produces "ietquay" but not "aresquay". Instead I get "uaresqay". What am I overlooking?

Here's the entire program:

```
def translate(input)
all_words = []
pig_word = ""
input.split.map do |word, i|
    if 'aeiou'.include? word[0]
        pig_word = word + "ay"
    else
        prefix = word[0] + "ay"
        pig_word = word[1..-1] + prefix
        if word.include? "qu"
            start_index = word.index("q")
            prefix = word[0..(start_index+1)] + "ay"
            pig_word = word[(start_index+2)..-1] + prefix
        end
        unless 'aeiou'.include? word[1]
            prefix = word[0..1] + "ay"
            pig_word = word[2..-1] + prefix
            unless 'aeiou'.include? word[2]
                prefix = word[0..2] + "ay"
                pig_word = word[3..-1] + prefix
            end
        end
    end
    all_words << pig_word
end
"#{[all_words].join(" ")}"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your special-casing for "qu" is being run, but then replaced by the logic in the `unless` with this condition:

```
   'aeiou'.include? word[1]
```

because the condition is `false` for `word = "square"` (because "q" is not in "aeiou").

A quick patch/fix is to use `if...elsif` to make the two competing conditional blocks mutually exclusive, and when the word contains "qu" it will not check further.

```
    if word.include? "qu"
        start_index = word.index("q")
        prefix = word[0..(start_index+1)] + "ay"
        pig_word = word[(start_index+2)..-1] + prefix
    elsif ! 'aeiou'.include? word[1]
        prefix = word[0..1] + "ay"
        pig_word = word[2..-1] + prefix
        unless 'aeiou'.include? word[2]
            prefix = word[0..2] + "ay"
            pig_word = word[3..-1] + prefix
        end
    end
```

Note this may not lead to a perfect translator, it just fixes the issue you have brought here as a question.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I know that my original code is full of poor style and I appreciate that you answered my question directly anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Implementing Neil's suggested edit, here is the fully-functional code:

```
def translate(input)
all_words = []
pig_word = ""
input.split.map do |word, i|

    first_vowel = word.index(/[aeiou]/) #dat first vowel occurence

    if first_vowel == 0 #words that begin with a vowel
        pig_word = word + "ay"


    elsif word.include? "qu" #words that don't begin with a vowel but include "qu".
        first_vowel = word.index(/[aeio]/) #first vowel not counting "u"
        start_index = word.index("q")
        prefix = word[0..(first_vowel-1)] + "ay"
        pig_word = word[first_vowel..-1] + prefix
    end


    if first_vowel >= 1 #words that don't begin with vowels or have "qu"
        prefix = word[0..first_vowel-1] + "ay" 
        pig_word = word[first_vowel..-1] + prefix
    end 


    all_words << pig_word
end
"#{[all_words].join(" ")}" 
end
```